# Espacio blanco al abrir el collapse de una de las card en material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Tengo dos cards agrupadas de manera horizontal y cada vez que trato de desplegar el contenido de una card se abren las dos card pero una card con el collapse en blanco.

La idea principal es que se pueda abrir el contenido de una card sin necesidad de desplegar el cuadro blanco de la otra e tratado con muchas posibles soluciones de muchas maneras y no he podido dar con el resultado que quiero.

comparto mi codigo actual

```
const AccordionSkills = () => {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (panel) => {
    if (expanded === panel) {
      setExpanded("");
    } else {
      setExpanded(panel);
    }
  };

    <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
      {data.map((skill) => {
        return (
          <Card
            sx={{
              width: "450px",
            }}
            key={skill.id}
          >
            <CardContent
              sx={{
                display: "flex",
                justifyContent: "space-between",
                "& .MuiSvgIcon-root": {
                  color: "#9032bb",
                  fontSize: "30px",
                },
              }}
            >
              <Box>
                {skill.icon}
              </Box>
              <IconButton onClick={() => handleChange(skill.namePanel)}>
                <ExpandMoreIcon />
              </IconButton>
            </CardContent>
            <Collapse in={expanded === skill.namePanel} unmountOnExit>
              <CardContent>
                {skill.skills.map((item) => {
                  return (
                    <Box sx={{ mb: "15px" }} key={item.id}>
                    </Box>
                  );
                })}
              </CardContent>
            </Collapse>
          </Card>
        );
      })}
    </div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Parece un problema de referencia a cada elemento de esa lista `data`, cada `card` tiene ya su identificador `key={skill.id}` referenciado , ahora debe haber alguna forma de llegar a al mismo desde `handleChange` porque asi parece que `handleChange` lo aplica a cada elemento

Comment: Hola compañero. cambie la validación ya no la hago por nombre si no por id y también le hice un seguimiento al método handleChange y envía el id de la card sobre la cual hago click y no funciona sigue igual.

Comment: Bien si ya confirmamos que las referencias apuntan correctamente entonces puede que sea una cuestion de CSS, veo que ese `Card` esta envolviendo con un CSS flex a los `CardContent`, puede que los estilos se apliquen por igual desde el elemento que envuelve hacia los children. Entonces cada que se expande un `CardContent` (se modifica su `height`), su otro par debe mantener el `heigth` sin expandir. Interesante